# iOS: Webfont displaying on home page, but not subpages

Tags: ios, webfonts

I'm building a new website for a client [here](http://www.damonsglendale.com/new/) - the embedded webfont displays just fine in Safari & Chrome (MacOS)... but only on the home page under iOS. On subpages in iOS, it defaults to Times Roman. The webfont files are located in the root.

Stumped. Any help? Here's my CSS:

```html
/**
 * @license
 * MyFonts Webfont Build ID 3124015, 2015-11-11T18:29:33-0500
 * 
 * The fonts listed in this notice are subject to the End User License
 * Agreement(s) entered into by the website owner. All other parties are 
 * explicitly restricted from using the Licensed Webfonts(s).
 * 
 * You may obtain a valid license at the URLs below.
 * 
 * Webfont: Tiki-Solid by Pelavin Fonts
 * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/pelavin/tiki/solid/
 * 
 * Webfont: Tiki by Pelavin Fonts
 * URL: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/pelavin/tiki/regular/
 * 
 * 
 * License: http://www.myfonts.com/viewlicense?type=web&buildid=*******
 * Licensed pageviews: 10,000
 * Webfonts copyright: Copyright (c) 2011 by Daniel Pelavin. All rights reserved.
 * 
 * © 2015 MyFonts Inc
*/


/* @import must be at top of file, otherwise CSS will not work */
@import url("//hello.myfonts.net/count/2fab2f");

  
@font-face {font-family: 'Tiki-Solid';src: url('webfonts/2FAB2F_0_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/2FAB2F_0_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/2FAB2F_0_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('webfonts/2FAB2F_0_0.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/2FAB2F_0_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
 
  
@font-face {font-family: 'Tiki';src: url('webfonts/2FAB2F_1_0.eot');src: url('webfonts/2FAB2F_1_0.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('webfonts/2FAB2F_1_0.woff2') format('woff2'),url('webfonts/2FAB2F_1_0.woff') format('woff'),url('webfonts/2FAB2F_1_0.ttf') format('truetype');}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { 
 font-family: Tiki-Solid; 
 font-weight: normal; 
 font-style: normal; 
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    letter-spacing: 4px;
      line-height: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your inspector. The font files are located at the root, but they're being looked for (and not found) in a subdirectory.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   http://www.damonsglendale.com/new/lunch/webfonts/2FAB2F_0_0.ttf

Rather than referring to them relatively, you could resolve this issue by specifying the entire path.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a try.